# How can I identify a namespace?

Tags: c#, namespaces, inversion-of-control

My team has a lot of IOC conventions that look something like...

```
if (type.Namespace == "My.Fun.Namespace")
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Of course, maintaining this kind of thing becomes brutal after awhile, and we would rather not. The only option I could think of was to store these all in one place, as string constants or something of that nature, but that isn't a lot better... We have been considering making classes that basically serve as namespace identifiers in order to have almost an anchor type to key off of, like, say...

```
if (type.Namespace == typeof(My.Fun.Namespace.MarkerClass).Namespace)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

But that just feels weird. So is there another way to solve this one that we just don't know about? If not, has anyone had any luck with the whole marker class concept?

Response to comments:

I didn't architect this and it isn't up to me to change it; I'm just hoping someone knows a better way to get a namespace. What I have outlined above is actually a snippet of code from inside one of the StructureMap conventions we're using. The convention scans an assembly for implementations of a given interface and, generally, gives preference to more specialized implementations--hence one found in "X.Y.Z" namespace is to be preferred over the base implementation found in "X.Y".

Comment: What exactly is the argument against an enum or a class with readonly properties?

Comment: Well, for me personally, I'd rather not have to keep that up to date.

Comment: Why are you checking namespaces in the first place? The point of an IOC container is you program against an interface.  Seems you are still coding against an implementation.

Comment: Sorry, Charlie, but I have no control over any of that.

Comment: I've noticed there's no response on this yet. I have spend some time looking into a T4 solution but had to give it up considering the template has no knowledge of your project's assemblies at compile-time. You can circumvent this however by compiling your project into an assembly and adding that as a reference to your template, but this will get pretty ugly. If you want to, I can post the code to generate an enum (or properties) but this will require you to pre-compile your project before being able to generate this.